# Unexpectedly found nil, but vars are not nil

Tags: swift

I am getting this error that says *Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:* but I am not implicitly unwrapping anything.... at least I don't think I am.

I'm only 5 days into Swift so if this is a uber noob question I am sorry.  I used my best google-fu and came up dry.

```
    func updateScores() {
    target1Score.text  = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget1)X"
    target2Score.text = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget2) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget2)X"
    target3Score.text = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget3) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget3)X"
    target4Score.text = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget4) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget4)X"
    overallScore = ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget2 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget3 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget4
    overallXCount = ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget1 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget2 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget3 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget4
    matchTotalLabel.text = "\(overallScore) - \(overallXCount)X"
}
```

The apps purpose is scoring, so you select which round you are in and then it opens the input UI and press a 'save' button, I was using segues but it was stacking VC's so I am using dismiss now with the struct setup so I can write to the originating VC's variables.

It is failing on the first line inside the function.  I have commented out everything else and it still fails, I have also tried using *self.target1Score.text* but it does the same.  I have tried doing the concatenation into another var and printing it and it works fine... but trying to assign that var to the UILabel.text is not working... I am hoping It is something simple that I have missed.

Here is the full code for this VC:

```
import UIKit

var mainVC = ViewController()

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    struct GlobalVars {
        static var scoreTarget1 = 0
        static var scoreTarget2 = 0
        static var scoreTarget3 = 0
        static var scoreTarget4 = 0
        static var xCountTarget1 = 0
        static var xCountTarget2 = 0
        static var xCountTarget3 = 0
        static var xCountTarget4 = 0
//        static var matchTotal = "0 - 0X"
//        static var overallScore = 0
//        static var overallXCount = 0
        
//        func updateScores() {
//            var target1ScoreText = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget1)X"
//            var target2ScoreText = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget2) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget2)X"
//            var target3ScoreText = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget3) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget3)X"
//            var target4ScoreText = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget4) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget4)X"
//            ViewController.GlobalVars.overallScore = ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget2 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget3 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget4
//            ViewController.GlobalVars.overallXCount = ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget1 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget2 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget3 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget4
//            ViewController.GlobalVars.matchTotal = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.overallScore) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.overallXCount)X"
//        }
    }
    //Variables
    var whatTargetIsThis = 0
//    var whatTargetWasThis = 0
    var matchTotal = "0 - 0X"
    var overallScore = 0
    var overallXCount = 0
//    var btnID = ""
    
    
    //Upper Display
    @IBOutlet weak var matchTotalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var matchTotalScore: UILabel!
    
    //Target Scores
    @IBOutlet var target1Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var target2Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var target3Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var target4Score: UILabel!
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "enterScoresSeg"){
                let entryVC = segue.destination as! ScoringUI
            entryVC.targetNumber = whatTargetIsThis
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        print("this was target number \(whatTargetWasThis)")
       // print(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1)
       // updateScores()
    }
    
    func updateScores() {
        target1Score.text  = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget1)X"
        target2Score.text = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget2) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget2)X"
        target3Score.text = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget3) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget3)X"
        target4Score.text = "\(ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget4) - \(ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget4)X"
        overallScore = ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget1 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget2 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget3 + ViewController.GlobalVars.scoreTarget4
        overallXCount = ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget1 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget2 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget3 + ViewController.GlobalVars.xCountTarget4
        matchTotalLabel.text = "\(overallScore) - \(overallXCount)X"
    }
    // Go-To Target Buttons
    
    @IBAction func targetBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.titleLabel?.text {
        case "Target 1":
            whatTargetIsThis = 1
        case "Target 2":
            whatTargetIsThis = 2
        case "Target 3":
            whatTargetIsThis = 3
        case "Target 4":
            whatTargetIsThis = 4
        default:
            break
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "enterScoresSeg", sender:self)
    }

}
```

And after it crashes it shows me what the vars were...

[crash output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpPXc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your IBOutlets are nil, and since they're implicitly unwrapped optionals, they're going to crash when you access them. That means you haven't wired them up in the storyboard, or that you're accessing them before the storyboard is loaded (probably by calling `updateScores` from outside the VC when the VC isn't loaded).

Comment: Thanks!  They are being called from outside the VC only because *viewDidLoad* doesn't work after I have dismissed the VC brought in by the VC.

Comment: Is there another way to have a func run when the overlaying VC is dismissed?  I tried using the completion in here but that also crashed/never built  *self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)*

Comment: You should never run anything on a VC after it is dismissed (and as a rule, you shouldn't call methods on view controllers at all). VCs should not hold data; they should just display data. Put the data in model object and make that model object a shared global instance (or pass it into the VC, but that's much harder to implement in UIKit, so I recommend beginners start with a shared global instance).

Comment: The method you want to implement for updating your view controller every time it comes on screen is `viewWillAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`. It will be called automatically (most of the time; there are some corner cases where `viewWillAppear` doesn't get called by UIKit when many of us expect it should be, but for basic work you shouldn't run into that).

Comment: Thanks again Rob!

It I have added 'viewWillAppear' and it is not being called after the other VC is dismissed.

I understand that the data should be held in a different location, this is just the first iteration and the code is dirty... however I don't think that would fix the underlying issue I am facing, correct?  The issue seems to be after dismissing the secondVC the mainVC does not run any function to update the UILabels.  I could run a loop with a timer but that seem wasteful and resource intensive.

Comment: A common cause of the problems you're describing are misunderstanding when a VC is created versus reused. It depends somewhat on what you're embedding this in (nav controllers, tab controllers, `present(...)` calls, and the like). In a few cases, UIKit doesn't behave quite as expected (or how it probably should). If you're having trouble, I'd simplify this down to a simple project that just navigated through VCs and log when all the delegates are called. If you still have questions with that, it's probably a good question for here (search a little, though; might have been asked).